# Why Django serves static files using the wrong MIME type?

Tags: django

On a new installation of windows 10, right after installing python v3.9.5, I do:

```
>pip install django
>django-admin startproject test1
>cd test1
>python manage.py migrate
```

And then I edit `test1/settings.py` only to set the STATIC_ROOT and disable DEBUG mode

`settings.py`

```
import os
...
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And then:

```
>python manage.py collectstatic
>python manage.py runserver
```

And finally, I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ and I see this:
[image]

Comment: You have set `DEBUG = False`, which means you are running in a production server. Django does not serve static files in a production server because it is inefficient. See [Deploying static files (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/) for more details

Comment: It did served them, but using the wrong MIME type

Comment: Also, I picked this specific scenario after having the same problem with MIME types with another app running in development mode (DEBUG = True)